# I am getting this foreign key error in Java Derby database when I run the code

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am getting this foreign key error in Java Derby database when I run the code

```
CREATE TABLE PURCHASE (
    $PURCHASEID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,$
    $PURCHASEDATE DATE,$
    $PURCHASEQUANTITY INT,$
    $CHICPRICE DOUBLE,$
    $CUSTNIC VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,$
    $PRIMARY KEY (PURCHASEID)$
       $ FOREIGN KEY (CUSTNIC) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTNIC)$
);
```

[Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42X01] Syntax error: Encountered "FOREIGN" at line 8, column 9.
Line 8, column 9

Comment: Don't you need a comma after PRIMARY KEY (PURCHASEID) ? nb not familiar with derby so could be wrong and do you need all the $s

Answer (score 1):

If you put a comma after primary key it should work fine

```
CREATE TABLE PURCHASE (
    $PURCHASEID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,$
    $PURCHASEDATE DATE,$
    $PURCHASEQUANTITY INT,$
    $CHICPRICE DOUBLE,$
    $CUSTNIC VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,$
    $PRIMARY KEY (PURCHASEID),$
       $ FOREIGN KEY (CUSTNIC) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTNIC)$
);
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
CREATE TABLE PURCHASE (
    $PURCHASEID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,$
    $PURCHASEDATE DATE,$
    $PURCHASEQUANTITY INT,$
    $CHICPRICE DOUBLE,$
    $CUSTNIC VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,$
    $PRIMARY KEY (PURCHASEID)$
       $FOREIGN KEY (CUSTNIC) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTNIC)$
);
```

Comment: It would help if you could point out the difference between your code and posted code (i  for one can't see it)

Comment: difference is the space between $ and FOREIGN

Answer (score 0):

try creating the table and then add the foreign key constraint with

```
alter table PURCHASE add FOREIGN KEY (CUSTNIC) 
REFERENCES CUSTOMER (CUSTNIC)
```

and there seems to be there is a ", " missing before FOREIGN